# Android Navigation Component change backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-navigation

I try to use android navigation component.
I have some interesting case in my app
I have some fragments: **A, B, C, D, E**
first I open **A -> B -> C**
But then I open fragment "C" and I need to change its back stack
it should be like **A -> D -> E -> C**

For onBackPressed navigation, I need to remove "B" fragment and add "D & E" fragments which were never open before

Comment: This is bad UX. Btw, you need to clear the backstack, and manually add the fragments you need. But again, this is wrong.

Comment: unfortunately it is enterprise with irts own case view. And "whait a minute"(c) its a hot keys in enterprise devise with buttons. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Changing the navigation is wrong, a user expect to view the previous screen when pressing back

Comment: I mean that it is not my desicion, thi is busines logic. Again its enterprise development. Client only say: I need this and this screen, and this and this logic, nothing else

Comment: Hello, have you found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The android navigation is a relatively new and I have not explored the whole library to confidently say that you cannot it lacks the ability to perform your use case. With that said you can add `app:popUpTo` to your action on the navigation resource file. This means that your fragment will always pop to the predefined fragment irrespective of what is on the back stack. Here is some code example:

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/c"
android:name="com.example.myapplication.C"
android:label="fragment_c"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c">

<action
    android:id="@+id/action_c_to_a"
    app:destination="@id/a"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/a"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>
```

Look at the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#kotlin)

Answer (score -1):

What I did in my case. I created common shared view model. So, all needed info for all fragments can be loaded once and then used.

Or you could use shared view model for common data or data that should be shared and special view models for each fragment. After that you can use both shared and special view models in your fragments

For your case my approach of navigation would be like this:

```
if (some_condition) {
    navController.popBackStack(R.id.A, false)

    navController.navigate(R.id.D)
    navController.navigate(R.id.E)
    navController.navigate(R.id.C)
else {
    // navigate another way
}
```